# How can I translate this to mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, xampp

I recently migrated from sql server to mysql and I am having trouble converting my sql stored procedures into mysql stored procedures.
This is my SQL SERVER stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetGrades  
    @GradeId int = 0
    ,@Name nvarchar(100) = ''
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    SELECT ISNULL(I.GradeId,0) as GradeId
      ,ISNULL(I.Name, '') as Name
      ,ISNULL(I.Details, '') as Details
      ,ISNULL(I.StatId, 0) as StatId
      ,ISNULL(I.CreatedById, 0) as CreatedById
      ,ISNULL(U.UserName, '') as CreatedByName
      ,ISNULL(I.CreatedOn, null) as CreatedOn

    FROM Grades I

        LEFT JOIN Users U ON U.UserId = I.CreatedById

    WHERE (I.GradeId = @GradeId OR @GradeId = 0)
      AND (I.Name LIKE '%' + @Name +'%' OR @Name = '')   
      AND I.StatId <> 2 

END

GO
```

And this is what I've done so far in mysql stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GetGrades
(   
     IN intGradeId INT  
    ,IN strName VARCHAR(1000)       
)
BEGIN
SELECT 
      gradeId
    , gradeName
    , details
    , statId
    , createdById
    , createdOn 
FROM grades 
WHERE (gradeId = intGradeId OR intGradeId = 0)
AND (gradeName LIKE '%' + strName +'%' OR strName = '');
END
```

When I execute this, this is the error message:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '+ strName +'%' OR strName = '')
AND statId = 1;
END' at line 16
```

Also, is there an ISNULL() function in mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GetGrades (   
     IN in_intGradeId INT, 
     IN in_strName VARCHAR(1000)       
)
BEGIN
    SELECT gradeId, gradeName, details, statId, createdById, createdOn 
    FROM grades 
    WHERE (gradeId = in_intGradeId OR in_intGradeId = 0) AND
          (gradeName LIKE CONCAT('%', in_strName, '%') OR in_strName = '');
END;
```